Shiny R Data Table (DT) floating point value display
I am working on a financial assignment based on stock market data, and I am using R and Shiny for working on the problem. I have created a dataframe to be displayed on the web page as a Datatable of Shiny.
I am using R Studio version: Version 2023.06.0+421 (2023.06.0+421) on  MacBook Pro (OS Sonoma).
The code in R is as follows:
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Portfolio Analytics"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId='ports', 
                        label='Portfolios', 
                        choices=c('Port 1', 'Port 2', 'Port 3'), 
                        multiple=F)
        ),
      
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           # plotOutput("distPlot")
          DTOutput('dtable')
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    {
      if (input$ports == 'Port 1') {
        bvk_idirect
      } else if (input$ports == 'Port 2') {
        bvksk_idirect 
      } else {
        bvk_idirect
      }
    },
  )

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

When I display the dataframe bvk_idirect, for example, as is, in the console, I get the following output:
> bvk_idirect
                           Stock.Name         Stock Allocated.Quantity Market.Value Yesterdays.Price
    1:         ASIAN PAINTS INDIA LTD ASIANPAINT.NS                  5        14550           2910.0
    2:          HAVELLS INDIA LIMITED    HAVELLS.NS                 10        18385           1838.5
    3:                    ITC LIMITED        ITC.NS                600       258180            430.3
    4: TATA CONSUMER PRODUCTS LIMITED TATACONSUM.NS                165       183909           1114.6

As you can see, in this dataframe, the columns titled Market.Value and Yesterdays.Price, have a normal single digit after the decimal place. These are the generated from the data, based on yahoo's data.
However, when this very dataframe is displayed as a part of Shiny R's Datatable (DT), I have the following table displayed:

Compare the two columns which I referred earlier, with the screen shot above. You will see floating points with 6-7 digits after the decimal point.
I don't know how to get rid of the additional unwanted decimal places shoved into my output. For example, 3rd row 5th column's value of 430.3 has become 430.2999878?
I tried formattedRounding() from DT library, and it did not work. Can someone help me with this please?

You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This post may help.  Put it this way: if we can't see your code, how can we spot any mistakes it contains?  That said, is this helpful?

Modified as per your suggestion...If you need data also, I can upload, but I think you get the problem...

Does this answer your question? DT and Shiny: Formatting numbers in a datatable with filters

The link in my first comment gives you your solution:    output$dtable <- renderDT({       datatable(d()) %>% formatRound(columns = 4:5, digits = 2)   }).  (Or whatever number of decimal places you wish.)

@Limey, as you can see in the last line of my problem statement, I have already tried this, without any success....

With respect, no, I cannot see that.  You told us you "tried formattedRounding()", but without showing us how.  Also, you've not given us a minimal reproducible exaple, so we can only surmise what you did.  Since the link I posted has an accepted answer, and since I tested my proposal and proved that it worked before posting, I have no option but to conclude you made a mistake and that this question is a duplicate.

Here is my MRE: `library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Portfolio Analytics"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
numericInput("decimals", "how many decimal places?", value = 1)
),
mainPanel(
DTOutput('dtable')
)
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
d <- reactive({
mtcars
})
output$dtable <- renderDT({
datatable(d()) %>% formatRound(columns = 2:3, digits = input$decimals)
})
}`

I tried with my data, and it is not working on the formatting of the decimal numbers part. OK, here is my data as a CSV:
Stock.Name,Stock,Allocated.Quantity,Market Value,Yesterdays Price
ASIAN PAINTS INDIA LTD,ASIANPAINT.NS,5,14550,2910
HAVELLS INDIA LIMITED,HAVELLS.NS,10,18385,1838.5
ITC LIMITED,ITC.NS,600,258179.9927,430.2999878
TATA CONSUMER PRODUCTS LIMITED,TATACONSUM.NS,165,183908.996,1114.599976

I tried with my data, and it isnt working on the formatting the decimal nums part. My coding on the formatRound is same, with minor differences. OK, here is my data as a CSV:
Stock.Name,Stock,Allocated.Quantity,Market Value,Yesterdays Price
ASIAN PAINTS INDIA LTD,ASIANPAINT.NS,5,14550,2910
HAVELLS INDIA LIMITED,HAVELLS.NS,10,18385,1838.5
ITC LIMITED,ITC.NS,600,258179.9927,430.2999878
TATA CONSUMER PRODUCTS LIMITED,TATACONSUM.NS,165,183908.996,1114.599976
You can read this CSV as a df and replace 'mtcars' and see if you have any luck...thanks for holding my hands on this irritant...

With your data, my code works as expected and formatRound(columns = 4:5, digits = input$decimals) controls the number of decimal places to which Market Value and Yesterdays Price are displayed.  Your problem must lie elsewhere.  A minimal reproducible example would have removed the need for much of this discussion.

Thanks Limey for putting up with my irritants, and it finally worked!!. Frustratedly, I upgraded to the latest version of R, and without any further modifications it all works like a charm, including your MRE, mtcars data and my bvk_idirect data, and on my app. Well, I am at loss of words. I agree that I should have included my formatRound() also for your calculation, for a better presentation of the problem. Will keep it in mind for future purposes. Thanks a lot for hanging on with me till the end...

Change server function in your code as below. It should work as you expected.
server <- function(input, output) {
  bvk_idirect <- bvk_idirect %>% mutate_at(vars(Market.Value, Yesterdays.Price), funs(round(., 1)))
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    {
      if (input$ports == 'Port 1') {
        bvk_idirect
      } else if (input$ports == 'Port 2') {
        bvk_idirect 
      } else {
        bvk_idirect
      }
    },
  )
  
}

